# [hydro] Error in move_base.launch

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch my move_base.launch, ( http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup ) , I got this error :

```
Trajectory Rollout planner initialized with param meter_scoring not set. Set it to true to make your settins robust against changes of costmap resolution
```

This is my base_local_planner.yaml file

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.01 #0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.005
  max_rotational_vel: 0.02 #1.0
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.002 #0.4
  
  acc_lim_th: 0.01 #0.06 #3.2
  acc_lim_x: 0.01 #0.05 #2.5
  acc_lim_y: 0.5 #2.5

  holonomic_robot: false
  dwa: true
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188847/%5Bhydro%5D-error-in-move_base.launch/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get rid of that message you should set the parameter *meter_scoring* to either true or false, depending on your preferences. At the end of your *base_local_planner.yaml* add:

```
meter_scoring: true
```

or

```
meter_scoring: false
```

It is recommended to use meter scoring (*meter_scoring: true*) when you expect that the resolution of your map might change.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-05**:
Thank you !!